# How to install PyQt on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, sip, pyqt

I want to install PyQt. This seems kind of complicated to install on OS X. I haven't found any precompiled packages of it (are there any? I would really prefer those).

So I downloaded PyQt. And SIP, because it depends on that. These files:

- http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Downloads/PyQt4/PyQt-mac-gpl-4.7.3.tar.gz
- http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Downloads/sip4/sip-4.10.2.tar.gz

Did a `python configure.py && make && sudo make install` on SIP -- installed without any problems.

Tried the same on PyQt -- and failed of course:

> /Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Headers/qglobal.h:288:2: error: #error "You are building a 64-bit application, but using a 32-bit version of Qt. Check your build configuration."

Ok, so I tried with `python configure.py --use-arch=i386`. Same error.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked without problems via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install pyqt
```

Note that there was also [PySide](https://wiki.qt.io/PySide). Although that seems like it is abandoned and does not support Qt 5. You probably can install it anyway via:

```
brew install pyside
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. So much outdated, useless information on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

A new version of Qt, esp. Qt 4.7 Beta, seems to fix this problem.

http://qt.nokia.com/developer/qt-qtcreator-prerelease

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [MacPorts](http://macports.org) to install pyqt, qt, and many other packages.  I haven't used the pyat package, but in general I've been pleased with MacPorts.  It also makes it easy to update various packages as bew versions come out.

Comment: I have made bad experiences with MacPorts in the past, that is why I am trying to avoid it. I also want to use PyQt with my system Python and not with any Python installed by MacPorts (not sure if MacPorts is handling that correctly).

Comment: On the contrary, I'm not sure that system Python is being handled correctly and instead trust the MacPorts Python install. Another vote here for MacPorts and the `py26-pyqt4` port.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using [PyQtX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqtx/files/) which is binary precompiled package of PyQt for OS X. Compiling it manually is a big hassle.